# MS Excel COUNTIF to math equation

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif, equations

For publication, I need to convert the following MS Excel formula to a math equation:

`COUNTIF($A$2:$A$10416,"<2")-COUNTIF($A$2:$A$10416,"<1")`

I use this to count how many times a number between 1 and 2 appears with the given range.

Can anyone help, please?
Thanks a lot in advance
Milos

Comment: There is no automatic way to convert formulas to equations. They're just different things. You need to write the equation yourself, based on the logic of the formula. Doing that is a mathematical problem, not computer related. Maybe you get better support at math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks, Máté
will try my luck at math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Milos ,, this can be solved by using simple mathematics first find the Largest then the  Smallest, largest which is <2  are 0 and 1,, if all values are integer (assuming list has 0 also),, then Subtracts Larger from Smaller. Better you [Edit] the post & share list of values you do have, will helps us to fix it !!

Answer (score -1):

Unless you actually need to describe the algorithm for a computer science journal, can't you just use set theory?

E.g.

[image]

Comment: Ps. To count, refer to the cardinality or size of a finite set |A| using vertical bar glyphs like for absolute value.